# ExtJS - Store proxy loading data using Array Reader

Tags: extjs, proxy, store

I am having problems loading an array of data from an external file into my store.

This is the file containing the data:

/data/contacts

```
[
        ["Lisa", "lisa@hotmail.com", "555-222-3333"],
        ["Bart", "bart@hotmail.com", "555-222-3333"],
        ["Homer", "homer@hotmail.com", "555-222-3333"],
        ["Marge", "marge@hotmail.com", "555-222-3333"]
]
```

This is my store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Contacts', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    autoLoad: true,
    alias: 'store.contacts',
    model: 'MyApp.model.Contact',

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        reader: {
            type: 'array'
        },
        url: '../data/contacts'
    }
});
```

This is my model:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Contact', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    alias: 'model.contact',

    fields: [
        {name: 'name', mapping: 0},
        {name: 'email', mapping: 1},
        {name: 'phone', mapping: 2},

    ]
});
```

And I am getting this error:

```
[E] Ext.JSON.decode(): You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: [
    ["Lisa", "lisa@hotmail.com", "555-222-3333"],
    ["Bart", "bart@hotmail.com", "555-222-3333"],
    ["Homer", "homer@hotmail.com", "555-222-3333"],
    ["Marge", "marge@hotmail.com", "555-222-3333"]


]
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I am doing wrong, or what I should do? Preferably I do not want to change the format of the array in the data file.

Comment: Can you share your model definition please

Comment: If you change to using an Ext.data.ArrayStore and remove the reader config, does it make a difference?

Comment: Is this the exact sample code that generates that error? If yes, does it have a BOM marker? This may be the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your guys' help. The error was caused by a silly mistake of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I realized what I did wrong. It was a very stupid user error made by me.

In my data file: /data/contacts, what I really had was this:

```
[
    ["Lisa", "lisa@hotmail.com", "555-222-3333"],
    ["Bart", "bart@hotmail.com", "555-222-3333"],
    ["Homer", "homer@hotmail.com", "555-222-3333"],
    ["Marge", "marge@hotmail.com", "555-222-3333"]

]


// [
//     {name: 'Lisa', email: 'lisa@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1212'},
//     {name: 'Bart', email: 'bart@simpsons.com', phone: '555-333-2212'},
//     {name: 'Homer', email: 'homer@simpsons.com', phone: '555-122-1212'},
//     {name: 'Marge', email: 'marge@simpsons.com', phone: '555-123-1212'}
// ]
```

I was previously testing other options for my JSON format, and I was silly enough to think that I could place comment //'s in a normal file.

Removing the comments from the file will fix the error. The array defined in this file can now be loaded into the store.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that the received JSON is invalid. You can check the validity online at http://jsonlint.com. If it is invalid it is the first thing to fix.

Then, I see the combination of ajax proxy and array reader for the first time in many years with Ext and I'm not sure it is supported.